# How do I fix this error in importing data in Dbeaver

Tags: sql, dbeaver

[image]

I tried to import data into Dbeaver from CSV file and this error happened. The columns in Csv files have been merged after being imported into Dbeaver.

I have set comma as delimiter but it didn't work. Importing data had been successful until recent with the same csv file and the same way Help me

Comment: When columns in a CSV file are merged after being imported into DBeaver, it might be due to the delimiter not being correctly recognized during the import process.

Comment: Edit your question: Put a line with three backticks ( ``` ) alone into your answer. Then, paste the first 10 lines of your CSV file just after that into your answer - include, if you can, one line at the top with the column names, delimited by comma like the rest of the data. Append one line, after you pasted, consisting, again, of three backticks:  ```

Comment: Put an example of lines of a working CSV and one that doesn't work. And put also a screenshot of your import settings...